# Get the user's home when sudo-ing in a script ran by root

Tags: bash, sudo, script

In the manpage of sudo I found the `-H` option, but I don't seem to understand how it works. The manpage says:

> The -H ( HOME ) option sets the HOME environment variable to the
>   homedir of the target user (root by default) as specified in
>   passwd(5).

In my understanding, the following should not happen:

```
root $ sudo -u sztomi -H echo $HOME
/root
```

But instead it should output `/home/sztomi` which is the home directory of the user sztomi.

How can I do this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't quoted `$HOME`, so the current value is being substituted *prior* to the execution of the *sudo* command. Surround it with single quotes `(')`.

---

**EDIT:**

As we noticed (see comments), sudo does not call a subshell to start the given command (therefore there is no shell expanding `$HOME`). The revised command would be:

```
 sudo -u sztomi -H bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```

Explained: `sudo` switches the user ID and then calls a `bash` shell which in turn takes the `echo $HOME`, substitutes the variable `HOME` by its value and finally performs the `echo` command.

Note that calling the subshell is only neccessary in this example to get the variable `HOME` substituted after *sudo* switched the user ID. It is not neccessary if you just want to start a single program without variable substitution in the target environment.

Comment: That outputs $HOME (without expansion)

Comment: hmm - sounds like there is no intermediate shell process. Try: `sudo -u sztomi -H bash -c 'echo $HOME'`

Comment: Yep, that works. Could it be that it's the shell dash and not bash? Anyway, please add this to the answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use ~sztomi to get the environment variable.

For example, this will list the contents to sztomi's home dir.

```
sudo -u sztomi ls ~sztomi
```

Comment: If only it worked with `~$username`...